# Woocommerce: Customize recalculate button to absorb taxes into total price

Tags: woocommerce

When creating manual orders, usually you have to set a custom price for the product. When clicking on "Recalculate", it calculates the taxes and adds them to it

Since I already have "Load prices by country" to get the system price and taxes,

Would it be possible for manual pricing to just calculate the tax according to the price set without adding the result to the total?

[image]

I'm seeing that the button has a *calculate-action* class:

[image]

Maybe if I find the function that that class triggers I can modify it for my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define tax and shipping country wise

1. Go to woocommerce -> settings -> Tax -> Standard rates and define taxes country wise
2. Go to woocommerce -> settings -> shipping and define shipping country wise

Reference URL : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/